# Find ranges in a column that contain consecutive zeroes and retrieve row number

Tags: vba, excel, range

I am trying to write in VBA a macro that searches a zero in column A, compares it to the cell in the same row but in column B, and if both are zero, and in the next row both columns are zero as well, the macro displays the first row where it found the first zero and the last consecutive row in which the last zero was.

I am currently writing it with a For each loop, searching in Column A and comparing with column B, but I have no idea on how to make it so that it continues searching until the column ends. I have to note that there could be more than one range with consecutive zeroes, therefore I imagine I need an array that stores the ranges, or at least the row numbers.

```
   Sub BuscaMargenCero()
'
'

'
    Dim ini() As Variant
    Dim fin() As Variant
    Dim UltimaFila As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim flag As Integer

    With Sheets("CÁLCULO Margen")
        UltimaFila = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

        i = 1
        j = 1
        flag = 0
        For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & UltimaFila)
            If cell = 0 And .Cells(cell.Row + 1, 6).Value = 0 Then
                If flag = 0 And (.Cells(cell.Row + 1, 2).Value = 0 And .Cells(cell.Row + 1, 6).Value = 0) Then
                    ini(i) = cell.Row
                    i = i + 1
                    flag = 1
                ElseIf flag = 1 And (.Cells(cell.Row + 1, 2).Value <> 0 Or .Cells(cell.Row + 1, 6).Value <> 0) Then
                    fin(j) = cell.Row
                    j = j + 1
                    flag = 0
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

I am not using Range.Find since I have read it only retrieves the first value found, and I want it to continue searching for more zeroes.

EDIT: To clarify my question, here's how the application should work

```
A     B

2     5
0     1
0     0
0     0
0     0
12    20
```

The output array should contain the range (in row numbers) 3 - 5

Comment: You are getting down voted because on this site we expect to be shown code that is not working with a specific question regarding why that code is not working, not asked to do it for you, or show you where to start.

Comment: "The output", what do you mean by this? Do you just want a message box saying "Rows 3-5!"?

Comment: I can show my code, and in fact I'll do it just now, but it is still a work in progress that isnt finished yet.
As for the output, it should be an array (or two, I really don't know) where it stores the first and last row for each range of consecutive zeroes.

Comment: Now that the question has been improved, can we get some reversals on these down-votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Autofiter on zeroes for each column. The first and last or each 'set' will be the first and last of each .Area within SpecialCells(xlcelltypevisible).

.AutoFilter requires a header row.

```
col A   col B
    2    5
    0    1
    0    0
    0    0
    0    0
   12   20
    0    0
    0    0
   12   20
```

Module code:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim a As Long, rws As Variant

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=0
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=0
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        ReDim rws(1 To .Areas.Count, 1 To 2)
                        For a = LBound(rws, 1) To UBound(rws, 1)
                            With .Areas(a)
                                rws(a, 1) = .Cells(1).Row
                                rws(a, 2) = .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
                            End With
                        Next a
                    End With
                End If
            End With
        End With
        if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
    End With

    For a = LBound(rws) To UBound(rws)
        Debug.Print rws(a, 1) & " to " & rws(a, 2)
    Next a
End Sub
```

Immediate window results:

```
4 to 6
8 to 9
```

Comment: Hello Jeeped, first of all thanks for helping me, I really appreciate your effort. I am having trouble using your code since it isnt filtering correctly. I tried on a separate sheet and your code is working so I assume is my fault. It is filtering only the first cell of the whole range, and because of it not being a zero it just ends the macro.

Comment: My only guess would be that your zeroes are infinitesimal decimal values that only look like zeroes due to cell format rounding but that is only a guess. I cannot determine the exact problem as I have no access to data that can reproduce it.

Comment: I think I know why: I'm using data with decimals and my zeroes show up as 0.00 instead of 0. Is there any change I can make to your code to fix this problem? I could alternatively add some lines before your code that turn the cell formating into integers.

Comment: Use Criteria! and Criteria2 with xlAnd operator. Record yourself adding an autofilter to one column then look at the code and adjust the code above to suit.

Comment: Thanks, the solution to the decimal problem was super easy, just setting the criteria to "0.00" instead of 0 solved it. Thanks again for everything!